Nuxt v-for sorting issue when array changes
I'm using nuxt and iterating over an array provided by a plugin:
the plugin is defined like so and queries the server depending on the value of searchType:
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
    const searchType = useState("searchType")
    const days = useState('days')
    const bug = useState('bug')
    const { pending, data: notes, refresh } =
        await useAsyncData('notes', () => {
            return $fetch(`/api/v1beta/notes`, {
                query: {
                    days: searchType.value === 'days' ? days.value : null,
                    bug: searchType.value === 'bug' ? bug.value : null
                }
            })
        }, { watch: [days, bug, searchType] })

    return {
        provide: {
            notesLoader: {
                pending,
                notes,
                refresh,
            }
        }
    }
})

Then in my index.vue I'm rendering the results like so:
<NoteCard v-for="note in $notesLoader.notes.value"
                :noteID=note :key="note" class="overflow-x-auto mb-5"/>

The values of the notes.value array are unique strings, and they look like so:
[
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-16%252Fworkspace-2.md",
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-16%252Fworkspace-1.md",
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-15%252Fworkspace-2.md",
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-15%252Fworkspace-1.md",
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-13%252Fworkspace-2.md",
  "2024%252Fmay.d%252Fworkspaces-2024-05-13%252Fworkspace-1.md"
]

I noticed that after notes are loaded by bug (a short list) and then switching back to days (which is a list that sometimes includes the short list), the results are rendered
out of order, and I can't tell why.
The server always returns results sorted by date, and I can also verify that in the Nuxt dev tools. When searching by "bug" the list might be a sub-list of a search by "days" (for example, a search by bug can result in ["12"] and then a search by "days" results in ["32", "12", "45"])
In cases that the results appear unsorted, I check the notes array in the nuxt dev tools and it's sorted, only the rendered result isn't. What's the reason for that?

Edit: it seems that putting the v-for in a parent div fixes the issue, though I'd still appreciate an explanation if anyone can provide one:
<div v-for="note in $notesLoader.notes.value" :key="note">
    <NoteCard :noteID=note class="overflow-x-auto mb-5"/>
</div>


Vue diffs v-for nodes based on key, and JS objects can't be easily compared for equality, so using an object as a key is not good practice.  Try a unique property on note, maybe id if your notes have such a property.

"note" is not an object here, it's a string representing the note's id (the note card component uses it to fetch the actual object). I think what's happening is that after looking for a note based on bug, it responds with an array of all the notes fitting the search (say "note123", "note222") and then switching to day search in responds with a bigger list that also contains them (say "note555", "note123", "note222"), and then it pushes the diff at the end instead of by the order it got them.
